# Problem with tf.SparseTensor and tf.while_loop

Tags: python, tensorflow

I face a problem when I try to change the shape of `tf.SparseTensor` inside a `tf.while_loop`. Let's say I have this sparse tensor:

```
indices = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5],
               [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5],
               [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4],
               [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5],
               [4, 0], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4], [4, 5]], dtype=np.int64)

values = np.array([7, 6, 7, 4, 5, 4,
              6, 7, 4, 3, 4,
              3, 3, 1, 1,
              1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4,
              1, 1, 2, 3, 3], dtype=np.float64)

dense_shape = np.array([5, 6], dtype=np.int64)

tRatings = tf.SparseTensor(indices, values, dense_shape)
```

So, I want to take a slice from the first 3 rows. I know for that purpose I can use `tf.sparse_slice` but this is an example. In my real code, I gather multiple rows from the sparse Tensor which they are not serial. The code I wrote is this:

```
subTensor = tf.sparse_slice(tRatings, [0, 0], [1, 6])

i = tf.constant(1)
def condition(i, sub):
    return tf.less(i, 3)

def body(i, sub):
    tempUser = tf.sparse_slice(tRatings, [i, 0], [1, 6])
    sub = tf.sparse_concat(axis = 0, sp_inputs = [sub, tempUser])
    return [tf.add(i, 1), sub]

subTensor = tf.while_loop(condition1, body1, [i, subTensor], shape_invariants=[i.get_shape(), tf.TensorShape([2])])[1]
```

which does't work for some reason when I run it. I get this:

```
ValueError: Dimensions 1 and 2 are not compatible
```

According to https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop it says that:

The shape_invariants argument allows the caller to specify a less specific shape invariant for each loop variable, which is needed if the shape varies between iterations. The tf.Tensor.set_shape function may also be used in the body function to indicate that the output loop variable has a particular shape. The shape invariant for SparseTensor and IndexedSlices are treated specially as follows:

a) If a loop variable is a SparseTensor, the shape invariant must be TensorShape([r]) where r is the rank of the dense tensor represented by the sparse tensor. It means the shapes of the three tensors of the SparseTensor are ([None], [None, r], [r]). NOTE: The shape invariant here is the shape of the SparseTensor.dense_shape property. It must be the shape of a vector.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.
First the problem in Tensorflow code. Change [this line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py#L593) to:

```
var.indices.set_shape(tensor_shape.TensorShape([None, shape[0]]))
```

Another small problem in your code. You have to use int64 type for indexing variable:

```
i = tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.int64)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you write me the line as it has to be? What is tensor_shape and shape? I am sorry for the trouble but I am new to this.

Comment: I think the problem is in tensorflow core code, so you should change the line into tensorflow installed on your machine (or make pull request to the tensorflow repository). In my answer i make link to the line of code into tensorflow rep, which you should found on your machine and change to `var.indices.set_shape(tensor_shape.TensorShape([None, shape[0]]))`.

Comment: Ok got it. Thank you very much for your time I will try it.